# Implementing unit testing in Nodejs express - unexpected failure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, unit-testing, express, mocha.js

**Unable to perform unit testing**

The problem is that the test is not passing, although the request and response data is added to the database when I perform the test. Kindly suggest some way to pass this test. The expected status code 200 is not happening with this test. The integration test is working on my app but i am unable to debug this unit testing error.

```
//testfile
var db = require('../mongodb'),
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
posts = require('../api/addTodo'),
should = require('should'),
testUtils = require('./utils');

describe("Add Api", function () {
    var dummyPost, id;
    before(function (done) {
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/todosdb_test', function() {
            console.log('Connected To:'+'mongodb://localhost:27017/todosdb_test');
            done();
        });

        dummyPost = new db.Todos({
            'admin': 'Dumm_admin',
            'text': 'Dummy',
            'completed': true 
        });

        dummyPost.save(function (err, post) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
            id = post._id;
        });
     });

     describe("Create Post", function () {
         it("should create a new todo", function (done) {
             var req = {
                 body: {
                     'text': 'Blah blah',
                     'completed': false
                 },
                session: {
                    'email': 'abc'
                }
             };

             var res = testUtils.responseValidator(200, function (post) {
                 post.should.have.property('admin');
                 post.admin.should.equal('abc');
                 post.should.have.property('text');
                 post.text.should.equal('Blah blah');
                 post.should.have.property('completed');
                 post.completed.should.equal(false);
                 done();
             });
                console.log(req);
                console.log(res);
                posts.add(req, res);

         });
     });
        after(function(done){
            db.remove({}, function (err) {
                if(err) {console.log(err);}
            });
            mongoose.disconnect(done);


           });
     });
```

```
// utils file
var responseValidator = function (expectedStatusCode, validationFunction) {
    return{
        json: function (statusCode, data) {
            statusCode.should.equal(expectedStatusCode);
            validationFunction(data);
        },
        send: function (statusCode, data) {
            statusCode.should.equal(expectedStatusCode);
            validationFunction(data);
        }
    }
                         };

         module.exports = {
          responseValidator
                          }
```

```
    //mongodb file
    var mongoose = require('mongoose')
    mongoose.Promise= require('bluebird')

    var schema1 = new mongoose.Schema({
     admin : String,
     text : String,
     completed : Boolean 
     });

    var schema2 = new mongoose.Schema({
    password : String,
    email: String
      });

     var Todos = mongoose.model('Todos', schema1);
     var Accounts = mongoose.model('Accounts', schema2);

    module.exports = {
    Todos,
    Accounts
    }

     //add api file
     var db = require('../mongodb');

       add = (req, res, next) => {
        todoRes = {
        text: req.body.text,
        completed: req.body.completed
    }

    console.log(req.session.email);
    db.Todos.findOne({ admin: req.session.email, text: todoRes.text })
        .then(function (response) {
            if (!response) {
                var todo = new db.Todos({
                    "admin": req.session.email,
                    "text": todoRes.text,
                    "completed": false
                });
                todo.save()
                    .then(function (response) {
                        res.send({ 'status': 'Todo is added' })
                    })
                    .catch(function (e) {
                        res.send({ 'status': 'failure', Error: e });
                    });
            }
            else {
                res.send({ 'status': 'todo already exist' });
                status:'todo already exist';
            }
        })
        .catch(function (e) {
            res.send({ 'status': e })
        })
     };

     module.exports = {
      add
     }
```

**Error message at terminal**

```
> mytodos-app@0.0.0 test /Users/sumitkumarsahu/Desktop/mytodos-app
> mocha --recursive ./test/unit.test.js



      Add Api
    Connected To:mongodb://localhost:27017/todosdb_test
        Create Post
    { body: { text: 'Blah blah', completed: false },
      session: { email: 'abc' } }
    { json: [Function: json], send: [Function: send] }
    abc
    Unhandled rejection AssertionError: expected Object {
      status: Error {
        operator: 'to be',
        expected: 200,
        showDiff: false,
        actual: Object { status: 'todo already exist' },
        stackStartFunction: Function { name: 'assert' },
        negate: false,
        assertion: Assertion {
          obj: Object { status: 'todo already exist' },
          anyOne: false,
          negate: false,
          params: Object {
            operator: 'to be',
            expected: 200,
            message: undefined,
            showDiff: false,
            actual: Object { status: 'todo already exist' },
            stackStartFunction: Function { name: 'assert' },
            negate: false,
            assertion: [Circular]
          },
          onlyThis: undefined,
          light: false
        }
      }
    } to be 200
        at Assertion.fail (/Users/sumitkumarsahu/Desktop/mytodos-app/node_modules/should/cjs/should.js:258:17)
        at Assertion.value (/Users/sumitkumarsahu/Desktop/mytodos-app/node_modules/should/cjs/should.js:335:19)
        at Object.send (/Users/sumitkumarsahu/Desktop/mytodos-app/test/utils.js:8:31)
        at /Users/sumitkumarsahu/Desktop/mytodos-app/api/addTodo.js:33:8
        at tryCatcher (/Users/sumitkumarsahu/Desktop/mytodos-app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/util.js:26:23)
        at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/sumitkumarsahu/Desktop/mytodos-app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:507:31)
        at Promise._settlePromiseAt (/Users/sumitkumarsahu/Desktop/mytodos-app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:581:18)
        at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/sumitkumarsahu/Desktop/mytodos-app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/promise.js:697:14)
        at Async._drainQueue (/Users/sumitkumarsahu/Desktop/mytodos-app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:123:16)
        at Async._drainQueues (/Users/sumitkumarsahu/Desktop/mytodos-app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:133:10)
        at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/Users/sumitkumarsahu/Desktop/mytodos-app/node_modules/bluebird/js/main/async.js:15:14)
        at runCallback (timers.js:672:20)
        at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:645:5)
        at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:617:5)
          1) should create a new todo
        2) "after all" hook


      0 passing (3s)
      2 failing

      1) Add Api Create Post should create a new todo:
         Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.


      2) Add Api "after all" hook:
         TypeError: db.remove is not a function
          at Context.<anonymous> (test/unit.test.js:57:20)



    npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Comment: First guess, you are returning too early in before().

Answer (score 0):

In your add api file you interface with send:

```
res.send({ 'status': 'todo already exist' });
```

but in your utils you expect to see a status code:

```
send: function (statusCode, data) {
   statusCode.should.equal(expectedStatusCode);
   validationFunction(data);
}
```

So the "error" is that `200 !== { 'status': 'todo already exist' }`

However, you are not throwing these errors to the test runner so instead of seeing the test error you are confronted with a timeout and the unhandled exception.  In order to catch these you will need to return the promise created by `posts.add` and rethrow exceptions.  I also took the liberty of fixing a potential double catch issue as well as fixed the promise chaining to make the next step work.

```
return db.Todos.findOne({ admin: req.session.email, text: todoRes.text })
    .then(function (response) {
        if (!response) {
            var todo = new db.Todos({
                "admin": req.session.email,
                "text": todoRes.text,
                "completed": false
            });
            // Need to return here to continue the promise chain!!
            return todo.save()
                .then(function (response) {
                    res.send(200, { 'status': 'Todo is added' })
                })
                .catch(function (e) {
                    res.send({ 'status': 'failure', Error: e });
                    throw e;
                });
        }
        else {
            res.send({ 'status': 'todo already exist' });
            status:'todo already exist';
        }
    }, function (e) { // Need to move this error handler here otherwise res.send can be called Twice!!!
        res.send({ 'status': e })
        throw e;
    });
```

Now we can wait for the test to finish.  I would also convert responseValidator to just be stubs and switch test to a promise based test, and I may do that later but let's focus on getting this to work....

```
var res = testUtils.responseValidator(200, function (post) {
             post.should.have.property('admin');
             post.admin.should.equal('abc');
             post.should.have.property('text');
             post.text.should.equal('Blah blah');
             post.should.have.property('completed');
             post.completed.should.equal(false);
             done();
         });
            console.log(req);
            console.log(res);
            // This is catch any exceptions (like an assertion) and pass it on the test runner
            posts.add(req, res).catch(done);
```

To fix the after, try:

```
    after(function(done){
        db.remove({}, function (err) {
            if(err) {console.log(err);}
            mongoose.disconnect(done);
        });
    });
```